# Javascript calling a function while having a mousestate of 'hold'

Tags: javascript, canvas, addeventlistener

I am creating a javascript canvas background and I want items on the screen to move only when I am holding down my mouse button (anywhere on the screen).

```
window.addEventListener('mousedown',function(e) {
       console.log("mousedown");
})
```

This is the code I have now. How can I a function be called while I am holding down the mouse button, and not just on-click?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're looking for the `mousemove` event. You'll also need a `mouseButtonDown` flag variable which you set in the `mousedown` event handler and reset when the mouse button is released. Now you can do stuff (like change coordinates of things that get drawn on the canvas) inside the `mousemove` function *if* `mouseButtonDown` is true.

Comment: First setup `mousedown` and `mouseup` listeners that toggle a certain globally scoped variable to `true` (on mouse down) or `false` (on mouseup). You can then use `window.requestAnimationFrame` to run a callback function on each browser repaint. In each run of the callback you should check whether the aforementioned global variable is set to true and react accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.addEventListener('mousedown',function(e) {
       holding = 1;
})


window.addEventListener('mouseup',function(e) {
       holding = 0;
})
```

If you use this, you can later check for if the variable of 'holding' is a 1 or a 0 as a conditional for a loop and have your function be running while holding == 1

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is an option for your question:

```
window.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
   console.log("mousedown");
   //function to start animation
   window.addEventListener('mouseup', function (e) {
      console.log("mouseup");
      //function to end animation
   })
})
```

In this way the mouseup listener would be created only when its animation is started.